# PHP/SQL: SELECT 2 columns 3 times with different values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to SELECT 2 columns twice with different value

```
SELECT id FROM ads WHERE onoff='1' AND again='0'
SELECT id FROM ads WHERE onoff='2' AND again='1'
SELECT id FROM ads WHERE onoff='3' AND again='1'
```

is there a way to do this all in one sql ?

Comment: Please could you try to rephrase your question, it simply makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT id 
FROM ads 
WHERE (onoff = '1' AND again = '0')
   OR (onoff = '2' AND again = '1')
   OR (onoff = '3' AND again = '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Better execution than using OR:

```
 SELECT id FROM ads WHERE onoff='1' AND again='0'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id FROM ads WHERE onoff='2' AND again='1'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id FROM ads WHERE onoff='3' AND again='1'
```

OR

```
SELECT ID FROM ADS WHERE onoff='1' AND again='0'
                      OR (onoff IN( '2','3') AND again = '1')
```